# Inserting but ignoring hyphens in asp.net URL routing

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

Im trying to create the following URLS using .net routing but in a webforms project

http://www.ebuyer.com/173389-startech-external-hard-drive-enclosure-black

So in my routing table I have the following

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{prodid}-{prodname}", "~/Ecommerce/product.aspx")
```

This works fine if prodname has no dashes, but if I force in dashes, the route is ignored. Is there anyway to handle this?

Also, instead of my making the urls SEO friendly myself, can this be done with some sort of pattern matching with URL routing?

Thanks

Update:

After researching this, I think this cant be done (or is very tricky). If I user IIS Url rewrite, I guess it might be easier but I am struggling to think of the regex pattern for this. Any help on this appreciated...